# UITabBar and UIMenuControl not appearing after going to another tab and back

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a UITabBar and a UIMenuControl but the problem is that when I click on the button and my MenuControl appears and then I switch to another tab and then when I come to the previous view and click that button again the UIMenuControl doesnot show up .
The UIMenuControl is not is no showing up when i come back from another tab. 
I dont know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want the tab bar to reappear, call:

```
self.tabBarController.hidden = NO;
```

If you are having trouble with losing it during a particular method, try putting this in that method.

The other possibility is that you are covering the first view completely. If this is the case, then be careful. You may be actually adding new views to the hierarchy every time you push a button. If you dont handle your memory management properly this would be a huge leak. A band-aid fix would be to call:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBarController];
```

Comment: Ok I've added a bit of an explanation